# Running docker on virtual Server- Possible or not?

Tags: linux-kernel, docker, virtual-machine, virtualhost

I'm trying to run/install docker on my vServer and can't find information if it's even possible.. I tried CentOS(6&7), Ubuntu, Debian, and fedora now and I'm just not able to get the docker daemon to run.

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since So 2015-04-05 17:12:23 EDT; 16s ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
  Process: 956 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d $OPTIONS $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS $INSECURE_REGISTRY (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 956 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 05 17:12:23 vvs.valentinsavenko.com systemd[1]: Starting Docker Applicati...
Apr 05 17:12:23 vvs.valentinsavenko.com docker[956]: time="2015-04-05T17:12:2...
Apr 05 17:12:23 vvs.valentinsavenko.com docker[956]: time="2015-04-05T17:12:2...
Apr 05 17:12:23 vvs.valentinsavenko.com docker[956]: time="2015-04-05T17:12:2...
Apr 05 17:12:23 vvs.valentinsavenko.com docker[956]: inappropriate ioctl for ...
Apr 05 17:12:23 vvs.valentinsavenko.com docker[956]: time="2015-04-05T17:12:2...
Apr 05 17:12:23 vvs.valentinsavenko.com docker[956]: time="2015-04-05T17:12:2...
Apr 05 17:12:23 vvs.valentinsavenko.com systemd[1]: docker.service: main proc...
Apr 05 17:12:23 vvs.valentinsavenko.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Ap...
Apr 05 17:12:23 vvs.valentinsavenko.com systemd[1]: Unit docker.service enter...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
[root@vvs ~]#  systemctl status docker.service -l
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since So 2015-04-05 17:12:23 EDT; 33s ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
  Process: 956 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d $OPTIONS $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS $INSECURE_REGISTRY (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 956 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 05 17:12:23 vvs.valentinsavenko.com systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Apr 05 17:12:23 vvs.valentinsavenko.com docker[956]: time="2015-04-05T17:12:23-04:00" level="info" msg="+job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)"
Apr 05 17:12:23 vvs.valentinsavenko.com docker[956]: time="2015-04-05T17:12:23-04:00" level="info" msg="WARNING: You are running linux kernel version 2.6.32-042stab094.8, which might be unstable running docker. Please upgrade your kernel to 3.8.0."
Apr 05 17:12:23 vvs.valentinsavenko.com docker[956]: time="2015-04-05T17:12:23-04:00" level="info" msg="+job init_networkdriver()"
Apr 05 17:12:23 vvs.valentinsavenko.com docker[956]: inappropriate ioctl for device
Apr 05 17:12:23 vvs.valentinsavenko.com docker[956]: time="2015-04-05T17:12:23-04:00" level="info" msg="-job init_networkdriver() = ERR (1)"
Apr 05 17:12:23 vvs.valentinsavenko.com docker[956]: time="2015-04-05T17:12:23-04:00" level="fatal" msg="inappropriate ioctl for device"
Apr 05 17:12:23 vvs.valentinsavenko.com systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 05 17:12:23 vvs.valentinsavenko.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Apr 05 17:12:23 vvs.valentinsavenko.com systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
```

On every system there is a different problem and I'm wasting hours and hours on not solving them ..

http://kb.odin.com/en/125115

This post suggests that it might not work at all on vServer with old kernels, like in my case..

Did anybody actually manage to use docker on a vServer and if yes, which Kernel does your host-system have?

I have a cheap server at https://www.netcix.de if that's important.

Answer (score 0):

The installation page has a section "[Check kernel dependencies](https://docs.docker.com/installation/binaries/#check-kernel-dependencies)" which clearly mentions the minimum kernel level to be expected for Docker to run:

> Docker in daemon mode has specific kernel requirements. For details, check your distribution in *[Installation](https://docs.docker.com/installation/#installation-list)*.
>
> **A 3.10 Linux kernel is the minimum requirement for Docker**. Kernels older than 3.10 lack some of the features required to run Docker containers. These older versions are known to have bugs which cause data loss and frequently panic under certain conditions.
>
> The latest minor version (3.x.y) of the 3.10 (or a newer maintained version) Linux kernel is recommended. Keeping the kernel up to date with the latest minor version will ensure critical kernel bugs get fixed

So if your distros have a kernel too old, or some other requirements not respected (as listed in [Installation](https://docs.docker.com/installation/#installation-list)), that would explain why the docker daemon fails.

Comment: I know the requirements, It's just that even updating the kernel of the systems doesn't help and my question was if that's because the physical host-server has a low kernel. - This is more about the internal structure of VMs i guess..

Comment: @user3768835 it is more about the VM indeed. I am on Windows(!) with a recent linux VM and docker works just fine.